# Cannot Give a Parameter To QT connect Function

Tags: c++, serial-communication, qt5.5

I implemented reading bytes at a serial communication in a Qt project(5.5) in Visual Studio 2013. 
My code is here:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    //QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    int argumentCount = QCoreApplication::arguments().size();
    QStringList argumentList = QCoreApplication::arguments();

    QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);

    if (argumentCount == 1) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Usage: %1 <serialportname> [baudrate]").arg(argumentList.first()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    QSerialPort serialPort;
    QString serialPortName = argumentList.at(1);
    serialPort.setPortName(serialPortName);

    int serialPortBaudRate = (argumentCount > 2) ? argumentList.at(2).toInt() : QSerialPort::Baud9600;
    serialPort.setBaudRate(serialPortBaudRate);

    if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        standardOutput << QObject::tr("Failed to open port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPortName).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Camera cam2;
    //cam2.showCamera();
    cam2.showCamera();
    cam2.showFullScreen();

    QByteArray abc;
    SerialPortReader serialPortReader(&serialPort,abc);

    //return coreApplication.exec();
    return app.exec();

};
```

serialportreader.cpp

```
#include "serialportreader.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

SerialPortReader::SerialPortReader(QSerialPort *serialPort, QByteArray abc, QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
, m_serialPort(serialPort)
, m_standardOutput(stdout)
{
    connect(m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead);       
}

SerialPortReader::~SerialPortReader()
{

}

void SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead()
{
    m_readData.append(m_serialPort->readAll());
    if (!m_readData.isEmpty()) {
        m_standardOutput << m_readData << endl;
        m_readData.clear();
    }

}
```

This code works successfully. I would like to set the contents of m_readData array to abc array so that I can evaluate the message in main scope. In order to implement this, I gave abc array to handleReadyRead function as a parameter. However, it gives an error.The code is here:

```
SerialPortReader::SerialPortReader(QSerialPort *serialPort, QByteArray abc, QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
, m_serialPort(serialPort)
, m_standardOutput(stdout)
{
    connect(m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead(abc));
}

SerialPortReader::~SerialPortReader()
{

}

void SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead(QByteArray abc)
{
    m_readData.append(m_serialPort->readAll());
    if (!m_readData.isEmpty()) {
        m_standardOutput << m_readData << endl;
        m_readData.clear();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
serialportreader.cpp(45): error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

line45:

```
connect(m_serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead(abc));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the local variable to the slot this way, but what you are trying to do doesn't even require it. You could just store `abc` to a member variable in the constructor, and use it in the slot. BUT: you have to change it to a reference, otherwise the call to the constructor copies the array, so the original one in your main function is unaffected.

You could also just implement this array as a member variable of your `SerialReader`, and provide a getter function, so that the `main` function (or whoever is the consumer of the data) can just pull this data from the reader instance.

Comment: I applied your second suggestion and it fixed my problem. However, I would like to wait main function after calling serialportreader till the getting some message at that communication. Because, I need that array after those operations. Thus, I have a synchronizing problem now.

Comment: As you are using Qt, the obvious way would be to emit a signal in the reader and create a slot were you do your processing